# Wrong modal shown to select next badge in profile

Tags: bug, badges, user-experience

After obtaining a new badge, two buttons show up in profile ("Summary" tab):

[image: Buttons in profile]

First of them ("Track the next one") opens a modal, which proposes to pick a badge of another kind:

[image: Modal to pick a badge]

I have obtained a regular badge (not sure how it should be called), while now the window proposes me to select a tag badge (which I'm already tracking in fact). This is persistent (so closing and re-opening the modal does not help). If I refuse to pick and select "Let us pick" button, next "regular" badge is selected properly, and cogwheel icon nearby opens the proper modal. (I'm not reporting wrong badge shown as "latest", because it is a caching issue and resolves a bit later, AFAIC)

[image: After clicking "Let us pick"]

Settings modal:

[image: Modal opened by cog button]

Comment: I had noticed that as well recently. I used the 'workaround' via the 'Let us pick' button as you have also described. Afterwards I could change it as expected. This comment is just to confirm that it's not a single occasion. Good that you have highlighted it here.